# Is it possible to make array size size depended on the atribute value(int)? c#

Tags: c#

Now my question is how can I make so when I make new object type Trip, 
arrayOfPeople will be size of value numberOfRooms?

```
class Trip
{
    private Person[] arrayOfPeople;

    public Person[] arrayOfPeople get { return arrayOfPeople; }
        set { arrayOfPeople = value; }

}

class Ship  
{

    private int numberOfRooms;


    public int NumberOfRooms
    {
        get { return numberOfRooms; }
        set { numberOfRooms = value; }
    }

}
```

I was thinking of making numberOfRooms static and then in Trip constructor just setting arrayOfPeople = new Person[Ship.NumberOfRooms] but I am not sure if that is right aproach.
Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you could just use a list. It is as efficient as an array in use

Comment: Careful when you use the word 'efficient'. It's not just as 'efficient' as a List will use more memory than a native array. You mean that it's just as 'performant' as an array (which is also incorrect, but the performance difference is pretty much negligible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in the code help to answer your question, so check it out :)

```
public class Trip
{
    // Define a constructor for trip that takes a number of rooms
    // Which will be provided by Ship.
    public Trip(int numberOfRooms)
    {
        this.ArrayOfPeople = new Person[numberOfRooms];
    }

    // I removed the field arrayOfPeople becuase if you are just
    // going to set and return the array without manipulating it
    // you don't need a private field backing, just the property.
    private Person[] ArrayOfPeople { get; set; }
}

public class Ship
{
    // Define a constructor that takes a number of rooms for Ship
    // so Ship knows it's room count.
    public Ship(int numberOfRooms)
    {
        this.NumberOfRooms = numberOfRooms;
    }

    // I removed the numberOfRooms field for the same reason
    // as above for arrayOfPeople
    public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; }
}

public class MyShipProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create your ship with x number of rooms
        var ship = new Ship(100);

        // Now you can create your trip using Ship's number of rooms
        var trip = new Trip(ship.NumberOfRooms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring data members at the top of a class's definition makes for much more readable code...

Comment: @SamusArin That's an opinion :) But if you want to put your properties at the top, by all means, go for it. If you want private field backings for every single property regardless of whether or not they are necessary, go for it :)

Comment: Visual Studio auto-generates class diagrams this way (fields, properties, methods), regardless of their lexical order. I'm not saying it's an industry standard, but Visual Studio is pretty standard.

Comment: @SamusArin That depends on your Visual Studio setup and your own/company's conventional standards. Where I work and how my VS is configured is Fields -> Constructors -> Properties -> Methods. We have it setup this way because we consider Properties as Methods (which they are under the hood). But, however you want to flavor it is totally up to you/your company. This one has no right or wrong answer.

Comment: @SamusArin That's good, as all developers should. However, class structure has nothing to do with self-documenting code... self-documenting code is the practice of writing your method names, variables, classes, etc. in a way in which their names describe who they are, or what they do, or what data they hold, etc. Your issue here is that you prefer your class structure to be a specific way (which is totally okay), but others may prefer it to be a different way (which is also totally okay). It's the same as if you prefer `number = number + 1` or `number += 1`.

Comment: The first thing I do after collapse (CTL-M, CTL-L) is expand the class to view members that I can search. It makes for an efficient and hassle free navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor for `Trip` that takes an integer parameter `public Trip(int numberOfPeople)` and inside that new up the array like you mentioned `arrayOfPeople = new Person[numberOfPeople]()`